# Lost in MSWord 2007 - How do I add Reviewers & change colors?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have three Reviewers in my MSWord2007 document right now.  I want to add a 4th Reviewer and can't figure out how.  If I access the list of Reviewers in the drop down menus re: Tracking Options, I just get the list but can't add to it.

Also, how do I distinguish which edits were made by which Reviewer?  Right now, I can set the colors for the different types of edits (deletions, additions, moves), but I don't know who made each change.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

K

Answer (score 1):

1. You don’t need to do anything to “add a fourth reviewer”
   – just let the fourth person turn on Track Changes and start editing.
2. “I don't know who made each change.” 
   On the “Review” tab, in the “Tracking” panel, click on “Show Markup”,
   and drag your mouse down to “Reviewers”.  A pull-right menu will appear. 
   It lets you show and hide markup on a per-reviewer basis,
   but the menu itself shows you the reviewers’ names in their respective colors.
   or
   Just hover over a tracked change.  You should get a pop-up box that says who made it.