# How to add multiple reviewers in Microsoft Word 2007 and at the same time keep track of interim document versions?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, review

I'm using Microsoft Word 2007. I've received a document which I need to revise, but the original document already has revisions built into it. I would like to be able to stack my revisions on top of those found in the original document, perhaps using a different reviewer name so that my changes can be distinguished from the original ones while preserving them.

Under the Review panel, I can choose among:

- Final Showing Markup
- Final
- Original Showing Markup
- Original

However, this list only seems to distinguish between final and original versions and does not seem to allow me to keep/view interim revisions of the document (which are neither original nor final versions).

Also under the Review panel, when I click on Show Markup -> Reviewers, all I see is one entry named All Reviewers (which also has a checkbox next to it). However, I don't see the possibility to add other reviewers there and am not sure about how this works.

Could anyone please help me accomplish the task at hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSWord 2007 - How do I add Reviewers & change colors?](http://superuser.com/q/823783/354511)

Comment: Well, the post mentioned above deals with some of the problem I asked about. However, what is still not clear to me is, if there is more than one reviewer, and each reviewer has their own review color, and there is no revision history, then it appears to me that all edits are bunched together in a haphazard manner. What happens if edits by different authors are made to the same words in the same place? What I was looking for was a way to manage a revision history, so that the document could have different versions, all stored with the document. Is this at all possible? Thanks.